# Have 17 subquery case statements, any better way to do this?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a really disgusting query that runs sorta slow:

```
SELECT TOP 10 d.AccountID, COUNT(mp.PhoneTypeID) AS Num_Phones,
sum(case when mp.PhoneTypeID = 1 then 1 else 0 end) AS type1,
sum(case when mp.PhoneTypeID = 2 then 1 else 0 end) AS type2,
sum(case when mp.PhoneTypeID = 3 then 1 else 0 end) AS type3,
sum(case when mp.PhoneTypeID = 4 then 1 else 0 end) AS type4,
sum(case when mp.PhoneTypeID = 5 then 1 else 0 end) AS type5,
sum(case when mp.PhoneTypeID = 6 then 1 else 0 end) AS type6,
sum(case when mp.PhoneTypeID = 7 then 1 else 0 end) AS type7,
sum(case when mp.PhoneTypeID = 8 then 1 else 0 end) AS type8,
sum(case when mp.PhoneTypeID = 9 then 1 else 0 end) AS type9,
sum(case when mp.PhoneTypeID = 10 then 1 else 0 end) AS type10,
sum(case when mp.PhoneTypeID = 11 then 1 else 0 end) AS type11,
sum(case when mp.PhoneTypeID = 12 then 1 else 0 end) AS type12,
sum(case when mp.PhoneTypeID = 13 then 1 else 0 end) AS type13,
sum(case when mp.PhoneTypeID = 14 then 1 else 0 end) AS type14,
sum(case when mp.PhoneTypeID = 15 then 1 else 0 end) AS type15,
sum(case when mp.PhoneTypeID = 16 then 1 else 0 end) AS type16,
sum(case when mp.PhoneTypeID = 17 then 1 else 0 end) AS type17
INTO #phoneshit
FROM #days d
INNER JOIN note.phone np on d.AccountID = np.AccountID INNER JOIN main.phone 
mp ON np.PhoneID = mp.PhoneID
GROUP BY d.AccountID
```

I can't think of any other way to filter the phone types into new columns like this, let alone a faster one. Anybody know of one? Just what's the best method in cases like this?

Comment: Well you could use dynamic SQL to turn out those `CASE` expressions.  This would probably reduce lines of code, but leave you with dynamic SQL which is harder to read.  Thanks for your candor in describing the query, by the way :-)

Comment: Are the joins happening on views or tables?Is main.phone a very big table?

Comment: your reading as well as writing into (#phoneshit) table . this will double the time I think

Comment: Not really. You're denormalising rows into columns, and sadly, that's probably the best way. You could maybe try a CLR function, but the speed gain would be tiny.

Comment: I try to be honest :P main.phone is large depending on your definition of large; 5 million rows or so. I've found in my testing that SELECT INTO works better than INSERT INTO type stuff, honestly. The top 10 is an artifact of my testing, btw, if it's not obvious :)

Damn, sad to hear. Figured there might be some odd edge case type thing I didn't know about. Cheers all

Comment: Maybe a "pivot" query?

Comment: Are there phone types outside of the 17?

Comment: nope, "just" 17

Answer (score 2):

For the performance problem you should consider to add an index on column `AccountID` of your `#days` temp table, the joins should be much faster.

For the 'readability' you can `PIVOT` on `PhoneTypeID`

```
;with
x as (
    select AccountID, PhoneTypeID
    from #days d
    join note.phone np on d.AccountID = np.AccountID
    join main.phone mp ON np.PhoneID = mp.PhoneID
),
p as (
    select *
    from x
    pivot ( count(PhoneTypeID) for PhoneTypeID in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17])) p
),
n as (
    select AccountID, COUNT(PhoneTypeID) Num_Phones
    from x
    group by AccountID
)   
select p.AccountID, n.Num_Phones, [1] type1, [2] type2, [3] type3, [4] type4, [5] type5, [6] type6, [7] type7 , [8] type8, [9] type9, [10] type10, [11] type11, [12] type12, [13] type13, [14] type14, [15] type15, [16] type16, [17] type17
into #phoneshit
from p
join n on p.AccountID = n.AccountID
```